# Which is a more maintainable way to construct objects?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, constructor

I am trying to learn design patterns, best practices, etc. There is a particular problem that always confuses me. 
**Abstraction is more important or KISS (keep it simple and stupid).**
Suppose I need to construct an object which several properties. There are 2 ways:

1) Instantiate the object and pass properties to the constructor.

```
$user = new user($user_detail_array); // one line code is enough
```

Benefits of this method:

- Code is small.
- Very good Abstraction.
- Short code so easily manageable.

Negatives:

- Adding new code causes problem,
- Difficult to follow DRY (don't repeat yourself).
- Violates single responsibility rule

2) Instantiate the object and set each property individually.

```
$user = new user();
$user->setName($name);
$user->setEmail($email);
$user->setGender($gender);
so on....
```

Benefits:

- it's easy to understand.
- Easy to change.
- It looks better.

Negatives:

- it's not good abstraction.
- All methods are visible.
- Long code to write. Trying to over follow KISS itself become difficult.
- Communication between classes become tough. Too many classes to communicate. So many public functions.
- It will be like procedure code.

In general what is the better way? If it depends on situation, when is the first approach better than the second? Why? I found that both approaches caused problems. The first method makes the code too abstract. The second method makes code too long and unmanageable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just misunderstood some concepts. First of all, KISS doesn't mean that you should write bad code without using abstraction. In fact, abstraction is one of the most powerful things that helps programmers write simple code.

The way you are going to design your program always depends on situation. If you are writing script that should run only once, do not even think about abstraction. It would be an overkill. However, if the lifetime of your program is pretty long, try to use abstraction and provide clients of your `user` class with intuitive and simple interface. Imagine, that code using `user` wants to change just it's name. In your first way they should provide `user` with the whole new array. In the second way you have just to call method `setName`. That's it.

To summarize: when you are designing a class, do not think about simplicity of writing this code. You should rather think about simplicity of using the class you are currently writing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$userBuilder = new UserBuilder();
$userBuilder.name = $name;
// and so on
$user = $userBuilder -> build();
```

It's abstract, doesn't repeat anything, and it adds another pattern (Builder).

Comment: ok, i am trying to learn it. but it's paradox, i found learning design pattern is tough. and design pattern are made to make things easy.

Comment: They are mainly designed to make things for later and/or others, really. Not for you when you write the code, but for you or somebody else maintaining it.

Comment: what value does this builder object provide over just setting properties on a `user` instance? Are you implying that `user` should be immutable?

Comment: @MattDavey, that's what I figured from the code OP showed. If it shouldn't, then name and so on are clearly properties.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 Yeah I think we need a bit more clarification from the OP. If it turns out his user entity is immutable I'll come back and upvote you :)

Comment: yes it will help me but it don't hit root cause. i remember 1 line, i am still confused but at higher level.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that I don't think there's much difference between your two examples.

Take the first example `$user = new user($user_detail_array);`. Yes this seems shorter, but in reality, what will we see usually before this line?

```
$user_detail_array = {
    "name" => "Bill",
    "email" => "billg@microsoft.com",
    "gender" => "male"
};
$user = new user($user_detail_array);
```

Wow, now it doesn't look so different from the second method...

```
$user = new user();
$user->name = "Bill";
$user->email = "billg@microsoft.com";
$user->gender = "male";
```

My point is, every property of the `user` entity will appear next to a `=>` (assignment) at some point in the program. Whether it's in array keys, properties of a builder object, or directly on the entity itself - they have to be assigned some time.

I think the best thing to do in this case is keep the assignments (`=>`) as close to the entity as possible, so it's most clear what is being assigned and where it is being assigned to.

Comment: I don't know any PHP at all, apologies if the syntax is wrong in my examples.

Comment: Thanks, don't worry, i can understand well. It helps me. but I concluded, design pattern helps us but they are not silver bullet. programming remains complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing about abstraction is that You don't need to set name, email and gender separately.

You can simply abstract them into the array and create a new setter:

```
$user->setUserDetail($userDetailArray);
```